# How to add transitive dependencies of Android archive in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, transitive-dependency

At our company, we have started modularizing our android projects and each has several dependencies. We use JFrog artifactory to host our aar files. Here is the code:

Library A:

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$googlePlayServices"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$googlePlayServices"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
```

The following does not work. I have also tried removing "@aar" but still nothing.
Main Projects:

```
compile ('com.sample.librarya:librarya:0.0.1@aar'){
    transitive = true
}
```

and hence I have to add retrofit dependencies to the main app again.

I have done a lot of research and read a lot of SO questions but none of them help hence this question. I also have all dependencies on LibraryA listed in its `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Try to add `compile "com.sample.librarya:librarya:0.0.1@pom"`

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Only thing is that first I put "@pom" tp download the pom and the had to replace it with "@aar" to use the aar file. How to download both aar and the pom file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add both following dependencies:

```
compile ('com.sample.librarya:librarya:0.0.1@pom')
compile ('com.sample.librarya:librarya:0.0.1@aar')
```

The first will download the pom and add all it's transitive dependencies on classpath. The second will download the aar.